# Jetbrains IntelliJ 13.1 - How to add Java Console Module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I want to add an blank Java Console Module to my existing Project, but I can't find an entry in the "New Module"-Wizard, which would fit. Older versions offered an template for this task. What is the fastest way to get an empty Java Module / Java Console App, without unnecessary dependencies? Do I need an plugin?

[image: Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 - New Module Wizard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:If you want the "template" u need to create a new project. This option does not exist in the module creation flow

1. Go to "Project structure"
   (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
2. In "Project settings" select "Modules"
3. Press <kbd>+</kbd> and select **Java** then **Next**[image]
4. Enter the desired module name and you have a new java module without any dependencies
   [image]

Comment: That's really weird but this workaround works for me. Obviously it's not even an JavaEE-Project although the Wizard let me choose an JavaEE Version.

Comment: I think the title selected for this module is not the best one since this module is for JavaSE applications. The JavaEE module is the next one...

Comment: I don't think this is a feature. It's somehow a bug and the only reason this is working could be, that this entry is an empty root node, which doesn't contain a template. It's also the only entry which doesn't have a checkbox for selection.